# What is the best way to know all concurrent running AWS Lambdas have ended?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am running multiple lambdas in parallel based on the s3 trigger. I want to get the end time to send back to the user when all the lambdas have ended their execution.

Comment: Could all lambdas store their start and end time in a database? Then you just need to pick the MAX(time) to figure out when everything was done.

Comment: But when should I query that? I know that is possible but I don't know when all lambdas have possibly ended!

Comment: How/when does the user read the information? Are they on a website? Do they get an email?

Comment: You might also consider Step Functions, if you need co-ordination.

Comment: Consider also that if you can have multiple users.

Comment: @Evert The email idea is suitable as my processes are long-running ones.

Comment: @jarmod is it possible to put lambdas in step function even if they are S3 event based?

Comment: When I read the question originally, I assumed that you had a single S3 trigger (related to a single S3 object upload) and, perhaps via SNS, you were then invoking multiple concurrent Lambdas. If that's the case, then you could instead of the SNS to Lambda fanout, you could trigger Step Functions processing. Unless you actually have multiple objects landing in S3 and they are all, in some sense, part of a transaction that you're trying to co-ordinate ...

Comment: @jarmod That's a good suggestion. I would try doing step functions. But I am looking for an alternative approach without step functions.

Comment: OK, assuming these Lambda invocations have some common correlator (e.g. the S3 object key) then perhaps you could perform an atomic write/increment to a DynamoDB counter whose item key is the correlator. When writing to DynamoDB you can request the item be returned so each Lambda will know if it was 1st, 2nd etc. to complete. You could trigger your follow up when the final write completes (whatever 'final' means to you). Or you could use DynamoDB Streams on this table, trigger a Lambda function on item puts and trigger the post-processing after a given item shows you that all have completed.

Answer (score 0):

If you need coordination between multiple lambdas, and something to happen when all of them are completed, your best bet is to use a Parallel Task in Step Functions, to run them in parallel and have an additional lambda as the next task after the Parallel one.  This is pretty much the standard use case for Step Functions/State Machines - maintaining "state" between Lambdas (including and beyond knowing when the others are complete).

This also gives you only a single entry point for your process as opposed to trying to replicate the data yourself to multiple lambdas.

Comment: The entry point of the architecture is an ecs fargate task followed by several s3 files which acts as triggers to a lambda that runs in parallel. I have a single entry point but not a single exit point.

Comment: hmm. So your architecture is -> EventOccurs -> ecs Fargate Task - > split into severa s3 files -> each s3 file triggers a different lambda -> then what? What happens after these lambdas trigger? Other lambds? Different actions? Do you need to bring it all back together? You can still use step functions for this but if its only one additional step after the lambda and they dont have to come back together, then having those individual lambdas just call the next step would work. IF they ahve to come back together (even if only 2  here and 2 there or what not) then parallel tasks in a sf